# How do I Find Work Done by a Non-Conservative Force?

Tags: physics, bulletphysics

How would I find the percent of mechanical energy lost to thermal energy due to friction if a 3.250g bullet enters a wooden block with a velocity of 80.00 m/s, and if it exits the block with a velocity of 20.00 m/s?

Thank-you!

Comment: This sounds more like a question for physics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the conservation of energy. "Non-Conservative Force" only means that use won't get the kinetic energy back by moving the bullet backwards.

Your system consists of the wooden block and the bullet. There is nothing else that can exchange energy so the whole energy is always the sum of

- the kinetic energy of the bullet (=m v^2 / 2)
- the thermal energy of the bullet
- the kinetic energy of the block
- the thermal energy of the block

At first everything but the kinetic energy of the bullet is zero.

If your block is very heavy and is not accelerated by the bullet, its kinetic energy will stay =0. So all the lost kinetic energy must have been converted to thermal energy.